# How to say ‘do you think that my German has improved’ in German

Tags: english-to-german

I am trying to write

> "Do you think that my German has improved?"

in German, but I have got

> "Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch verbessert werden hat?"

Is this the correct way to say it?

Comment: Ich glaube, dein Deutsch hat sich nicht verbessert. Die Regularien verbieten normalerweise Korrekturlesen. Versuche bitte eine konkrete Frage zu stellen, die zeigt, wo das Problem liegt! Ansonsten versuche doch in einem Wörterbuch oder im Netz nach Beispielsätzen zu suchen.

Comment: Where did you get that from? [Google translate](https://translate.google.de/#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=de&text=do%20you%20think%20that%20my%20German%20has%20improved) works nicely.

Comment: Do not recommend Google translate, seriously.

Comment: google translator is much improved now.

Answer (score 2):

I try to distill a grammar question from this.

*Do you think that my German has improved?*

> <s>Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch verbessert werden hat.</s>

This translation is *almost* correct. Only one word wrong and one missing. And at the same time, its totally wrong because it mixes up several time forms and voices.

The most straightforward translation is:

> Glaubst du, dass **sich** mein Deutsch **verbessert** hat?

The verb *sich verbessern* is the reflexive form of the verb *verbessern*. Something *got better*. You need the reflexive form here because this is active voice. Consider

> Glaubst du, dass *der Schüleraustausch* mein Deutsch **verbessert** hat?

Now *der Schüleraustausch* is the subject of the subordinate clause and you don't need a reflexive pronoun any more. Still active voice.

If you want to employ passive voice as in the English example, try

> Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch **verbessert ist**?

That's *Zustandspassiv*. It uses the *sein* auxiliary and the *Partizip II*. You can tell the passive voice when you bring up *der Schüleraustausch* again. It becomes a prepositional object.

> Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch *durch den Schüleraustausch* **verbessert ist**?

*Vorgangspassiv* in past tense is also an option.

> Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch *durch den Schüleraustausch* **verbessert wurde**?

---

Though, German speakers often use a predicative phrase with an adjective in comparative instead, and drop in a time marker:

> Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch *seit dem Schüleraustausch* **besser ist**?

Answer (score 2):

The best German version is certainly

"Glaubst du, dass sich mein Deutsch verbessert hat?"

However, you could also say

"Glaubst du, dass mein Deutsch besser geworden ist?"